# Bib file with apostrophes gives error during compilation

Tags: bibliographies, apostrophe

I have the following bib entry in my file:

```
@inproceedings {prekopa1980logarithmic,
title={Logarithmic concave measures and related topics},
  AUTHOR = {Pr\'{e}kopa, Andr\'{a}s},
  booktitle={Stochastic programming},
  year={1980},
  PUBLISHER = {Academic Press, London-New York}
}
```

and I get the undefined control sequence error

```
<argument> Pr\8
               0
l.383 \bibitem[Pr\80]{prekopa1980logarithmic}
                                             
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

I have other escape characters in the bib file but for some reason this particular entry is problematic. The problems disappears if I remove the escape characters.

Any tips on how to fix this would be highly appreciated.

My bibliography settings are

```
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{references}
```

I don't use any bibliography package but I am using my university's dissertation template which comes with some proprietary package.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) The correct syntax for accents should be `\'{e}` and `\'{a}` instead of `'{e}` and `'{a}`. You can check [this webpage](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters) for the syntax of accentuated characters

Comment: Thank you @KersouMan. I actually had \' instead of ' but I just realised the escape character wasn't displaying here on stack exchange. Edited it now to make it visible

Comment: Then, unfortunately, you will have to provide some compilable snippet that reproduces your error so that people are able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the error with

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings {prekopa1980logarithmic,
title={Logarithmic concave measures and related topics},
  AUTHOR = {Pr\'{e}kopa, Andr\'{a}s},
  booktitle={Stochastic programming},
  year={1980},
  PUBLISHER = {Academic Press, London-New York}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\cite{prekopa1980logarithmic}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

After running `pdflatex`, `bibtex` and `pdflatex` again, this produces

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> Pr\8
               0
```

The problem is in how the author name is input: there should be additional braces around the accented letters.

```
@inproceedings {prekopa1980logarithmic,
title={Logarithmic concave measures and related topics},
  AUTHOR = {Pr{\'{e}}kopa, Andr{\'{a}}s},
  booktitle={Stochastic programming},
  year={1980},
  PUBLISHER = {Academic Press, London-New York}
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much!!